# Refresh Particular Action Method Not All Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC application with One Controller ( having three Action Methods and 3 views). I need to Display View 1 for 5 seconds and then send a Call to Second Action Method of Same Controller to display View2.

The Problem is every time I Call Action Method 2, whole controller is refreshed i.e. Action Method 1 is refreshed as well. Please advise how can I refresh/execute/call only the Action Method of my choice, not all methods of controller.

I use following code to call second Action Method from my View1.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url="/MyController/ActionMethod2" />
   <title> Queue Stats</title>
</head>
```

**As Result Of Above Call : All Action Methods in MyController refresh and then ActionMethod2 is called.**

Comment: I don't understand what _"Action Method 1 is refreshed"_ means? I don't think "refreshed" is the right word.

Comment: It means "Call" or Execute the Method  named "Action Method" of MyController Class. I need to Call functionality of Method2 but without disturbing resources / parameters of Method 1. I am unable to avoid refreshing/ re calling of Method 1.

Comment: What are you trying to protect in the logic of Method 1 that you don't want Method 2 resetting?  One thought would be to store Method 1's data in a Model, or even in Session if it is that important, then pass in the Model for Method 2.

Comment: Ok - I am writing data in a File in Method1 now Using the Code:  System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");

Comment: Above Code Line runs fine for first time when the Call to Method2 is made it gives error i.e. File is already open. Even I closed the stream Writer Object at end of ActionMEthod1

Comment: @BaseerUlHassan - You do understand that HTTP is stateless, don't you? When you call ActionMethod1 and open a file handle, the request ends and then the file stream is removed from memory (without disposing it) and the file handle will remain open indefinitely. Any additional calls will not be using the same stream object, and you won't be able to open the file because it has an open handle. You should ensure the stream is disposed after every call.